# Minimum distance between selected point and remaining points in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, distance

I want to build a knn algorithm that works this way: I have a list of vectors and I select one of them. The function calculates the distances between the selected vector and the remaining ones from the list. The output would be the closest vector to the selected point and its corresponding (minimum) distance.

What I have right now is two separate functions. The first one computes a matrix with all distances and the second one computes the nearest neighbour.

My goal is to have a single function that preferably uses the for loop.

```
a <- c(10.5, 87.6)
b <- c(24.5, 39.7)
c <- c(12.2, 20.7)
d <- c(23.53, 77.7)
e <- c(10.2, 74.40)

list1<-list(a=c(10.5, 87.6),b=c(24.5, 39.7),c=c(12.2, 20.7),d=c(23.53, 77.7),e=c(10.2, 74.40))
list2<-list(a=c(10.5, 87.6),b=c(24.5, 39.7),c=c(12.2, 20.7),d=c(23.53, 77.7),e=c(10.2, 74.40))

listEuclideanDistances <- function(list1, list2){
  matrixDistances <- matrix(nrow = 5,ncol=5)
  colnames(matrixDistances) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
  rownames(matrixDistances) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")

  d<-0
  for(i in c(1:length(list1)))  {
    for (j in c(1:length(list2))){


      d<-0
        for(z in c(1:(length(list1[[i]])) ))  {
          d = d + (list1[[i]][z]-list2[[j]][z])^2
      }
      d = sqrt(d)
      print(d)
      matrixDistances[i,j] <- d
    }

  }
return(matrixDistances)

}

distances <-listEuclideanDistances(list1,list2) #to see the values of eucledian distance

bestKnnEverMade <- function(matrixDistances, position){
  minimunDistance <- 100000000 # just initializing the variable
  nameOfNeighbour <- "" # just initializing the variable
  columnnames <- colnames(matrixDistances)

  for(i in 1:nrow(matrixDistances)){
    currentValue <- matrixDistances[position,i]  

    if( (currentValue < minimunDistance) && (currentValue > 0) ){
      minimunDistance <- currentValue
      nameOfNeighbour <-  columnnames[i]
      }

  }
  return (c(nameOfNeighbour,minimunDistance))
}

bestKnnEverMade(distances,2)
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `dist` for your distance matrix calculation.

Comment: Also, any reason you are using `list`s instead `matrix`s to store your points?

Comment: I do not see the difference between your list1 and list2.